# Show that $p(x) = x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2-x-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has exactly $2$ nonreal roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that $p(x) = x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2-x-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has exactly $2$ nonreal roots.

$p(x)$ is irreducible:

Observe that we may express $p(x)$ as $$p(x) = x^5+5x^4+10x^3+10x^2+5x+1-6x-3 = (x+1)^5-6x-3.$$ Since $-1 \in \mathbb{Q},$ it follows that if $p(x-1)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x],$ then $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ also. We check that $p(x-1) = x^5-6x+3$ is irreducible. Since $3 \mid -6, \hspace{1mm} 3 \mid 3, \hspace{1mm} 3 \nmid 1$ and $3^2 \nmid 3,$ it follows that $p(x-1)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's Criterion. Hence $p(x)$ is also irreducible.

Graphing the polynomial shows that $p(x)$ crosses the real axis three times, so at most $p(x)$ has $2$ complex roots (how to show that there exactly $2$?) 
Also, what is another way to show polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}$ have a specific amount of roots in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Hint: Binomial Theorem (Just looking at the coefficients)

Comment: don't the coefficients need to be $1,5,10,10,5,1$?

Comment: You can write it as:
$$(x + 1)^5 - 6x - 3 = 0$$
At least, that /might/ help.

Comment: @StVincent: Nearly the same thing here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84002/ , at least the first part.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Not really, only the irreducibility part.

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun Thank you, that's useful

Comment: The last part is about to notice that $p'(x)$ has exactly $2$ real roots, so $p(x)$ can't have more, than $3$ ones. Considering signs of $p(x)$ on the roots of $p'(x)$ along with $p(\pm\infty)$ we conclude that there are exactly $3$ real roots.