# Generalization of irreducibility test .

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there any other tests other than Eisenstein's general irreducibility test . And i wonder if it is possible to extend it to more than one variable . looking forward to get some response.

Answer (score 5):

Much more powerful techniques for deducing irreducibility and factorization properties arise by applying valuation-theoretic concepts embodied in the notion of a *Newton Polygon*. For some references see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23877/23500)

Answer (score 4):

There are well known : [Cohn's irreducibility criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) and [irreducibility criterion of Perron](http://rms.unibuc.ro/bulletin/pdf/53-3/perron.pdf) .

Answer (score 3):

For a test closely related to Eisenstein's:

There was a [nice article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.118.01.003) by David A. Cox in the *Monthly* ("Why Eisenstein proved the Eisenstein Criterion and why Schönemann discovered it first", Volume **118** no 1 (January 2011), pages 3-21).  It gives:

**Schönemann's Irreducibility Criterion.** *Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients and positive degree. Assume there is a prime $p$ and an integer $a$ such that
$$f(x) = (x-a)^n + pF(x),\qquad F(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x];$$
if $F(a)\not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $p^2$.*

The test implies Eisenstein's criterion: say $f(x) = a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$ with integer coefficients, $\gcd(a_n,p)=1$, $a_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, and $a_0\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$. Multiply by a suitable integer so that $a_n\equiv 1\pmod{p}$; then we can write 
$$f(x) = x^n + pF(x)$$
with $F(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and $F(0)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Hence $f(x)$ is irreducible modulo $p^2$, and hence over $\mathbb{Z}$.