# The polynomial $(X^2+2)^n+5(X^{2n-1}+10X^n+5)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove that for any postive integer $n$, the polynomial
>   $$(X^2+2)^n+5(X^{2n-1}+10X^n+5)$$
>   is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

I have try use Eisenstein's criterion and can't it

Comment: You're right that Eisenstein's criterion won't help directly.  The only divisor of the coefficient of $X^{2n-1}$ is 5 and $5$ does not divide the constant term, $25+2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an immediate application of the [Schönemann's Irreducibility Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107152). It also follows by reducing modulo $5$ twice.

Comment: What do you mean by "reducing mod 5 **twice**"?

Comment: Reduce once, draw the conclusions, cancel $(X+2)^n$ and then $5$, reduce again.