# Show that the equation $x^3+7x-14(n^2+1)$ has no integral root for any integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Show that the equation
$$x^3+7x-14(n^2+1)=0$$
has no integral root for any integer $n$.
My work:
I consider the contraposition that there are integer roots.
Assume that the roots are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$
We have, $\alpha\beta\gamma=14(n^2+1)$
We also have, $\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=7$
Since $n^2\ge 1$, we get, $\alpha\beta\gamma\ge 28$
Now, I have no idea! Please help!

Comment: Note that $14$ is a multiple of $7$. What does that tell you about a putative integer zero $k$ of the polynomial?

Comment: Sounds like Daniel Fischer is riffing a theme by Eisenstein?

Comment: So, you mean, $\alpha\beta\gamma=2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)(n^2+1)$, which says that 1 of the 3 roots are even. But, I cannot conclude something more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 7\mid x^3\Rightarrow\ 7\mid x.\ $ Substitute $\, x = 7y,\,$ cancel $7,\,$ then deduce  $\,7\mid n^2+1,\,$ contradiction.

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, $ $ prime $\,p\mid x^k\!+pnx\, \Rightarrow\,  p\mid x^k \Rightarrow p\mid x \Rightarrow p^2\mid x^k\!+pnx\ $ if $\ k\ge 2$

This may be viewed as a special case of [Eisenstein's criterion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23877/242)

Comment: Is there a result that says $7| (n^2+1)$ is not true?

Comment: @Tapi $7\mid n^2+1\iff \bmod 7\!:\ n^2\equiv -1,\,$ so we  need only check that $-1$ is not a square $\bmod 7$, i.e. $\,x^2+1\,$ has no roots $\bmod 7,\,$ verifiable either by brute force checking the few cases, or, more generally, by Euler's criterion or quadratic reciprocity - [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2424097/242).

Answer (score 4):

Consider $x^3+7x-14(n^2+1)\equiv0 \mod (7)$, we get $x^3\equiv0 \mod(7)$ and therefore $x\equiv0 \mod (7)$.

Assume $x=7t$, then $(7t)^3+7\cdot 7t-14(n^2+1)=0$. i.e., $7^2t^3+7t-2(n^2+1)=0$. Similar, $7^2t^3+7t-2(n^2+1)\equiv0\mod (7)$, one has $2(n^2+1)\equiv0 \mod (7)$, which is impossible for integer $n$. So the equation has no integral roots.

Comment: how do we show that $7t-1$ can never be a perfect square ?