# Proving $11$ never divides $64^n +22^n -2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

More specifically I want to prove for any $n\geq 1$, $11\nmid 64^n +22^n -2$, and I'm having doubts as to the validity of my proof.

So, if $11$ did indeed divide $64^n +22^n -2$ for any $n\geq 1$, then, working modulo 11 would yield
$$
\bar{64}^n +\bar{22}^n -\bar{2} = \bar{0} \text{  (mod11)}
$$
but notice that $\bar{64}=\bar{-2}$ and $\bar{22}=\bar{0}$. Thus, $\bar{(-2)}^n +\bar{0}^n -\bar{2} =  \bar{(-2)}^n - \bar{2} = \bar{0}$. Computing a few values of $\bar{(-2)}^n$, we find, $\bar{-2}, \bar{4}, \bar{8}, \bar{5}, \bar{1}, \bar{-2}$, and so more specifically, $\bar{(-2)}^n$ is periodic with period 5 and never equal to $\bar{2}$ within that period, so the equality $\bar{(-2)}^n - \bar{2} = \bar{0}$ can  never hold for any $n\geq1$.

Let me know if this proof is sufficient or if I need to add or change anything, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Your proof looks fine. If (or when) you know about quadratic residues, an alternative is to note that $\left(2\over11\right)=\left(-9\over11\right)=\left(-1\over11\right)=-1$ (since $11\equiv3$ mod $4$).

Comment: bug: $\,(-2)^3\equiv -8$ (not $8).\,$ Luckily $\,-8\not\equiv 2\,$ so the proof still works.

Comment: @BarryCipra Another argument for $(\frac{2}{11})=-1$ is that $(\frac{2}{p})=1$ for a prime $p$ holds if and only if $p$ is of the form $8k\pm1$ , which $11$ is not.

Comment: Generally it's easier to use Euler's Criterion as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2424097/242) in the linked dupe, i.e. $\bmod 11\!:\ 2\equiv  8^{2n}\overset{(\ \ )^{\Large 5}}\Longrightarrow -1\equiv (8^n)^{10}\equiv 1\,$ contra lil Fermat. The comments using reciprocity are essentially doing the same thing.