# Proving a quadratic equation has no integral roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, square-numbers, euclidean-algorithm

Question:

> Show that the quadratic equation $x^2-7x-14(q^2+1)=0$ where $q$ is an integer ,has no integral real roots.

My approach :

Let for any integer $x$ the quadratic equation $=0$, Then 
$x(x-7)=14(q^2+1)$. We easily observe $2\mid x(x-7)$ . Now $7\mid x$ or $7\mid {(x-7)}$. In any of the cases $x=7m$ ($m$ belongs to integer) . Thus $7m(m-1)=2(q^2+1)$ , so $7 \mid {(q^2+1)}$ , therefore $q^2+1=7t$ or $q^2=7n+6$ Now if somehow we can prove that no perfect square could be represented as $7n+6$, By contradiction we will prove the question .

My problem

- how do we prove that no perfect square could be represented as $7n+6$.
- Please correct if my proposed solution is wrong at any step.
- Other elegant solutions will also be highly appreciated.

Thanks..!

Comment: Wouldn't you get $x(x-7)=14(q^2+1)$?

Comment: Correcting it very sorry

Comment: It is easy to confirm that no square is $6\pmod 7$.  Just check the $7$ residues $\pmod 7$ and confirm that you can't get $6$ as a square.  More abstractly. if $g^2\equiv 6\pmod 7$ then $g$ has order $4$ $\pmod 7$ which is not possible.

Comment: @lulu, you should put that as an answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the equation $x^3+7x-14(n^2+1)$ has no integral root for any integer $n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635938/show-that-the-equation-x37x-14n21-has-no-integral-root-for-any-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that no perfect square $k^2=7n+6$, we work with $k=7m\pm l; l\in0,1,2,3$

$$(7m+0)^2=49m^2=7(7m^2)+0$$
$$(7m\pm1)^2=49m^2\pm14m+1=7(7m^2\pm2m)+1$$
$$(7m\pm2)^2=49m^2\pm28m+4=7(7m^2\pm4m)+4$$
$$(7m\pm3)^2=49m^2\pm42m+9=7(7m^2\pm6m+1)+2$$

None of these are of the form $7n+6$, thusly it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-7x-14(q^2+1)=0 \implies \frac{7\pm \sqrt{49+56(q^1+1)}}{2}$$
In oder the roots are integer they need to be rational first.
The discriminant $105+56q^2$ needs to be perfect square of an integer ($n$). Then
$$56q^2-n^2=105$$
$q$ and $n$ being integers RHS is can have rational factors but LHS does not have rational factors like $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. So the roots will be real but they cannt be  even rational, so we conclude no integer roots.